# Remove word "Category" from WooCommerce product page

Tags: categories, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to remove the word Category from the product page.

[image]

As far as I know the code that displays that is woocommerce_template_single_meta located into content-single-product.php file:

```
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
```

I would like to know how I can modify and customize this hook, so I would be able to place it where I want and use my own styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will definitely remove the word "category". Add this code in functions.php.As you already know `woocommerce_template_single_meta` is the hook responsible for meta information of the single-product.

File is present in `/woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php`. Either you can use the following code to edit the HTML of meta.php or you can copy the file meta.php to `themes/your-theme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`.  Then edit the meta.php as you want it to be.

```
<?php

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta_remove_category', 40 );

function woocommerce_template_single_meta_remove_category(){    

    global $post, $product;

    $cat_count = ( !empty( $cats ) && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ) ? 
count($cats) : 0;

    $tag_count = ( !empty( $tags ) && ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) ? count($tags) : 0;

?>
<div class="product_meta">

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

  <?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>
     
    <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php _e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku" itemprop="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>.</span>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( '', '', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>

  <?php echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>

  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>

</div>

<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it removes everything, but I'm trying to remove only the word.

Comment: which theme , you are using

Comment: Custom theme I designed, based on bootstrap and underscores

Comment: @Kevin I have edited the code above this will definitly do what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you @terminator, it worked. I must say that the explanation is a bit confusing, I just replaced from **<div class="product_meta">**... to the closing div in the **meta.php** file. When adding the code in **Functions.php** it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kevin it didn't work?

Comment: When I changed the code into the meta.php file it worked.

Comment: it should work in both cases,, may be you doing something wrong.. anyways you solved by modifying meta.php, thats also fine. I myself use this approach ... I justed wanted to tell you about both the ways. happy coding